# Cannot convert float64 column to pandas object

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with the below columns:

```
id     |name
------------
1111.0 | sam
2222.0 | mike
3333.0 | john
```

and so on. The id column is recognized as a float 64 data type by pandas.

What I want:

```
id   |name
------------
1111 | sam
2222 | mike
3333 | john
```

I tried:

```
df= df.id.astype(str)
```

and

```
df=df.id.apply(str)
```

but it still doesn't convert it to an object. The issue has something to do with the way the data is read from excel. I know if I construct the whole dataset in python from scratch I can resolve this but it is not practical.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think reason should be some missing values, so you can use [`integer_na`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), only necessary pandas 0.24+:

```
df.id = df.id.astype('Int64').astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that has worked for me, without introducing aditional code, was working on the excel file removing blank spaces and replacing them for 0. Also check if is not mixed with text.
Sending print(yourrow) would help to check if you have a NaN(not a number) present. After a lot of researching i could figure that the.0 display was because of this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).